# Digital Ocean for Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5, hosting, web-deployment, digital-ocean

Up to now I have only used fully managed web hosting services like godaddy etc.

I would like to transition to digital ocean for improved performance and control.

Using digital ocean for hosting.  I'm looking for the best current method of deploying laravel 5.2 web apps, maintaining the app using GIT and maintaining/updating/patching the digital ocean cloud server.

I think from what I've read the best option is to use the laravel forge service which would build the server environment including services like MYSQL and the new letsencrypt secure certificates.

So my requirements are-

```
Push app deployment linked to GIT.
MYSQL
PHP 7
laravel homestead
Mail server like mailgun
letsencrypt 
Nginx and LEMP on UNIX distribution appropriate for laravel
Composer
Firewall
```

Is laravel forge capable of automatically updating required security patches, upgrades for PHP and MySQL etc?

Or do you need to maintain the environment after the deployment?

Comment: Your need to deploy laravel app on digital ocean in Ubuntu os is it right.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good answer to this here- https://laraveltips.wordpress.com/category/forge

Closing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create Ubuntu Droplet in Digital Ocean. Then log in through ssh root@your_ip.
Then Refer this link **https://kirubhawork.wordpress.com/2019/08/29/deploy-laravel-on-digital-ocean** to install lemp,git,mysql,php,composer,three months free ssl by let's encrypt in digitalocean.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working through this guide below.  It's pretty detailed and is Laravel specific.  Good if you want to deploy on your own.

[great tutorial by jacurtis at DevMarketer](http://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx/)

Comment: please post your answer and then references.